# О еде: слово "жрец"

Tags: семантика, однокоренные-слова

Есть такая шутка, что жрец — это тот, кто любит плотно покушать. А действительно, имеют ли что-то общее слова "жрец" и "жрать"? И русское ли слово "жрец"? Насколько я знаю, жрецы у славян назывались волхвами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Волхвы и жрецы - не одно и то же.Волхвы -  маги, мудрецы, предсказатели.Жрецы - посредники между богами и людьми, они приносили жертву богам. Жертва - огненное приношение богу. От глагола *gerti - жертвовать(от того же корня, что гореть, греть)Принести в жертву поначалу означало "сжечь". Сначала у славян не было посредников, каждый глава рода  был жрецом.Потом появились жрецы, которые якобы трактовали волю божества и поедали жертвенную пищу вместе с богами, не сжигая её, а готовя на огне.Тот, кто ест жертву, - жрец. Произошло переосмысление.Этому послужило сближение значений двух древних глаголов. Параллельно существовал глагол* gьrаti - глотать, кот. восходит к и.е. *girati -жрать, глотать (родств. горло).Звучали они одинаково, вот и слились в одном значении. Получается, что жрец — однокоренное со словом «жрать» и «жертва».

Comment: Тем не менее, утверждение, что волхвы - это аналог жрецов на славянской культуре, вполне уместно.  
По сути же - согласен.